# Parâmetro em negrito C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, winforms, textbox

Tenho a seguinte string:

`string frase = string.Format("A data de hoje é: {0}", DateTime.Now.Date);`

Há algum modo de deixar o parâmetro em negrito?

Comment: Onde você irá exibir essa string?

Comment: @AyrtonGiffoni em uma xrLabel do devexpress

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit:

passe o valor para sua variável:

```
string frase = $"A data de hoje é: <b>{DateTime.Now.Date}</b>";
```

No local que seu `XRLabels` recebe o a variável `frase`, substitua o `XRLabels` por um `XRRichText`.

`XRLabels` destinam-se a exibir texto simples apenas.

`XRRichText` foi projetado especificamente para exibir texto formatado em seus relatórios.

Referências: [aqui](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/7094/Concepts/Report-Controls/Rich-Text) e [aqui](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T282071/how-to-make-some-part-of-the-text-bold-in-xrrichtext)

Comment: Não posso usar assim, não acesso o `xrLabel` diretamente. Mando os dados pra uma classe de negócio, pra tratar junto com outros dados e aí sim começar a montar um relatório.

Comment: Em qual parte você acessa o xrLabel? na classe de negócio? é só vc usar desta maneira lá...

Comment: Em algum lugar você vai ter o acesso a classe label e vai ter o parametro da frase. Passe ele conforme descrevi acima e no método que você tem acesso ao xrLabel, você faz essa configuração. Se precisar de ajuda com isso, só postar o local que vc envia a string e a classe que recebe.

Comment: editei o post, vê se ajuda...

Comment: tentei usar seu exemplo, mas o `xrLabel` não tem uma definição para `AllowHtmlString `

Comment: Você tem razão. XRLabel é destinado somente a textos simples. Você deve trocar o XRLabel por um XRRichText que foi projetado especificamente para exibir texto formatado em seus relatórios. Editei novamente o comentário. Veja se te atende agora

Comment: agora sim, troquei o componente e pude mandar a string com tags html.

Answer (score 3):

A formatação é só para organizar o texto, estilos depende da saída que está usando.

Se é console é uma coisa, se é arquivo é outra e depende do formato que ele precisa, se é impressora depende dela e da tecnologia usada para gerar a impressão, se é web tem que usar HTML ou fazer como o gerador que está usando pede, se é GUI tem que ver como faz isso na tecnologia usada, varia se é Windows Forms, WPF, UWP, GTK, Xamarin iOS, Android, etc.

Este código pode ser usado assim:

```
var frase = $"A data de hoje é: {DateTime.Now.Date}";
```

Com a informação da tecnologia usada podemos usar assim no `XRRichText`:

```
seuLabel.Text = $"A data de hoje é: <b>{DateTime.Now.Date}</b>";
```

Mas se quiser usar o *label* que é mais leve (ainda que todos os componentes da DevXpress não sejam leves), pode fazer:

```
seuLabel.Font = new Font("nome da fonte", 11, FontStyle.Bold);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/DateInterpolation.cs).

Mas não pode fazer um parte do texto no mesmo *label*, pode fazer em mais de um colocados lado a lado.

Documentações:

- [`XRLabels`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRLabel.members)
- [Propriedade `Font`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRControl.Font.property)
- [Classe `Font`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.fontstyle?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

Comment: vou usar em uma xrLabel do devexpress, no report viewer, tenho vários parâmetros numa string, mas preciso que só um deles seja em negrito

Comment: Então tem que ver nessas tecnologias como tornar algo em negrito, na manipulação do dado não deve e não pode fazer isto. A documentação: https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRLabel.members. Especificamente terá que mexer na fonte: https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRControl.Font.property. NO caso usa a fonte padrão do .NET: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font(v=vs.110).aspx, propriedade `Bold`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.bold(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: a solução foi usar outro componente do devexpress, o `xrRichText`. Com ele dá pra passar a string com tags de html.